# When is $\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}$ rational?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Here's what I have so far:

$$\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b} = m/n \implies  a^2 + b^2 -2\sqrt{ab} = (m/n)^2$$
Therefore, $\sqrt{ab}$ must be rational, $ab$ must be a perfect square. Also,

$$\left(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}\right)\left(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}\right) = a - b$$

Therefore, in order for $\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}$ to be rational, $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$ must also be rational for all $a$ and $b$ such that $a \neq b$.

Is this a good enough answer?

Comment: What is this $!$ next to $a$ in the last line?

Comment: $\sqrt{18}-\sqrt{8}$...

Comment: Thanks @Arthur (I will delete this comment)

Comment: $\sqrt{\pi^2}-\sqrt{(\pi-1)^2}$ is rational... What restrictions do you have on $a$ and $b$?

Comment: $\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}\in\mathbb{Q}\implies(\sqrt{a}\in\mathbb{Q}\wedge\sqrt{b}\in\mathbb{Q})\vee(\sqrt{a}\not\in\mathbb{Q}\wedge\sqrt{b}\not\in\mathbb{Q})$

Comment: Of course, it doesn't help with the other direction, which is what your question is all about...

Answer (score 1):

If you require $a,b$ to be rational and unequal, then your last part is not quite finished: since $\sqrt a-\sqrt b$ and $\sqrt a+\sqrt b$ are both rational, their sum, $2\sqrt a$ and their difference $2\sqrt b$ must also be rational.